# How much degree of freedom of a rigid body in $N$-dimensional space?

Tags: classical-mechanics, spacetime-dimensions, rigid-body-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom

Well I have the answer it is
$\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ but what the procedure to derive it .

I tried this.
1).I have $N$ number of translation freedom.

To calculate the number of rotational freedom I tried this.

I have $N^2$ number of constraints. From expression.

$L_iL_j=\delta_{ij}$

$i,j$  can be chosen in $N$ different ways so $N \times N$.  So what next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are n degrees of freedom which come from its position (say of its center).

Furthermore, there are n(n-1)/2 rotational degrees of freedom. This is since they correspond to SO(n), the special orthogonal group of n-dimensional matrices which has dimension n(n-1)/2.

Comment: Ohh that's the reason . thanks